# JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT)

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm having problem with the user of Codehaus Jackson. I have an object with the next attributes and mapper declaration:

```
public class AuthenticatedPrincipal implements Serializable, Principal {
      @JsonIgnore
      private final static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper().enable(DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY).enableDefaultTyping(ObjectMapper.DefaultTyping.NON_FINAL)
      .setSerializationInclusion(JsonSerialize.Inclusion.NON_NULL).setVisibility(JsonMethod.FIELD, JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY);

  private String name;

  private Collection<String> roles;

  private Collection<String> groups;

  private boolean adminPrincipal;
...
  @JsonIgnore
  public String serialize() {
    try {
      return mapper.writeValueAsString(this);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to serialize Principal:" + toString(), e);
    }
  }

  @JsonIgnore
  public static AuthenticatedPrincipal deserialize(String json) {
    try {
      return mapper.readValue(json, AuthenticatedPrincipal.class);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Unable to serialize Principal:" + json, e);
    }
  }
}
```

That is used from another class:

```
public class AuthRequest {

  @Transient
  private AuthenticatedPrincipal principal;
  @PreUpdate
  @PrePersist
  public void encodePrincipal() {
    if (principal != null) {
        this.encodedPrincipal = principal.serialize();
    }
  }

  @PostLoad
  @PostPersist
  @PostUpdate
  public void decodePrincipal() {
    if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(encodedPrincipal)) {
        this.principal = AuthenticatedPrincipal.deserialize(encodedPrincipal);
    }
  }
}
```

When I execute the funtionality that generate a String like this:

```
Principal:{"adminPrincipal":false,"displayName":"sdfas","groupAware":false,"name":"sdfas"}
```

When the method AuthenticatedPrincipal.deserialize(encodedPrincipal); is called parsing a Json parameter but that method fail with this error:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT), expected START_ARRAY: need JSON Array to contain As.WRAPPER_ARRAY type information for class com.trent.app.lib.principal.AuthenticatedPrincipal
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@40fa255; line: 1, column: 1]
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: is that the full json generated by the `serialize` method?

Comment: just in case you have time, if you get the sources of Jackson, you can debug it to see what objects and data are being managed when error occurs.

Comment: Yes Fran, That is the full json that need to be serialize.

Answer (score 1):

```
Principal:{"adminPrincipal":false,"displayName":"sdfas","groupAware":false,"name":"sdfas"}
```

Is not valid JSON. It needs to look like this

```
{"adminPrincipal":false,"displayName":"sdfas","groupAware":false,"name":"sdfas"}
```

(without the `Principal:` at the start)

Comment: Your're right Simon, that's not a valid Json, I put the object print, I just checked the String parameter and it's a valid json  {"adminPrincipal":false,"displayName":"sdfas","groupAware":false,"name":"sdfas"}