# Spring Boot 3.0.0 with ElasticSearch 8: Unexpected JSON event

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I have a Spring boot 3.0.0 API which I'm trying to integrate with elastic search java client version 8.5.1

For context I have my elastic search running on elastic.co

Whenever I try to run a search or index a document I get the following error:

```
co.elastic.clients.json.UnexpectedJsonEventException: Unexpected JSON event 'VALUE_NUMBER' instead of '[START_OBJECT, KEY_NAME]'
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpUtils.ensureAccepts(JsonpUtils.java:105) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.JsonpDeserializer.deserialize(JsonpDeserializer.java:75) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.ObjectBuilderDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectBuilderDeserializer.java:79) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.json.DelegatingDeserializer$SameType.deserialize(DelegatingDeserializer.java:43) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.getHighLevelResponse(RestClientTransport.java:280) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport.performRequest(RestClientTransport.java:148) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1518) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient.search(ElasticsearchClient.java:1535) ~[elasticsearch-java-8.5.1.jar:na]
    at com.poc.es.elasticsearchspringboot.connector.ESClientConnector.fetchUserById(ESClientConnector.java:126) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.poc.es.elasticsearchspringboot.service.impl.ESServiceImpl.fetchUserById(ESServiceImpl.java:57) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.poc.es.elasticsearchspringboot.controller.ESRestController.fetchUserById(ESRestController.java:29) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:207) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:152) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1080) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:973) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1003) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:705) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:880) ~[spring-webmvc-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:814) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:6.0]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:223) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.2.jar:6.0.2]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:185) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:158) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:542) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:119) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:357) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:400) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:861) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1739) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.1.jar:10.1.1]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) ~[na:na]
```

On elastic I created my index via the PUT request for the index and confirmed its created.

Below is the code I'm using to connect to ES:

```
package com.poc.es.elasticsearchspringboot.config;

import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchClient;
import co.elastic.clients.json.jackson.JacksonJsonpMapper;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.ElasticsearchTransport;
import co.elastic.clients.transport.rest_client.RestClientTransport;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.client.config.RequestConfig;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;


@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class ESRestClient {

    private String hostName = "https://xxxxxxx.gcp.cloud.es.io";
    private int port = 9243;
    private String username = "elastic";
    private String password = "xxxxxxxxxxx";

    @Bean
    public ElasticsearchClient getElasticSearchClient() {

        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost(hostName, port, "https"))
                .setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigBuilder -> requestConfigBuilder
                        .setConnectTimeout(5000)
                        .setSocketTimeout(60000))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder ->
                        httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider))
                ;

        // Create the low-level client
        RestClient restClient = builder.build();

        // Create the transport with a Jackson mapper
        ElasticsearchTransport transport = new RestClientTransport(restClient, new JacksonJsonpMapper());

        // And create the API client
        return new ElasticsearchClient(transport);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<UserProfile> fetchUserById(@PathVariable("id") String id) throws RecordNotFoundException, IOException {
        UserProfile employee = esService.fetchUserById(id);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(employee);
    }
```

UserProfile Model:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Data
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class UserProfile {

    private String userId;

    private String name;

    private String currentTitle;

    private String displayName;

    private String profilePicUrl;

    private String gitHubUserName;

    private String profileLink;

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(userId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return ((UserProfile) obj).getUserId().equals(userId);
    }
}
```

Service:

```
public interface ESService {
    UserProfile fetchUserById(String id) throws IOException;
}
```

Service Impl:

```
@Service
public class ESServiceImpl implements ESService {

    @Autowired
    private ESClientConnector esClientConnector;
    
    @Override
    public UserProfile fetchUserById(String id) throws IOException {
        return esClientConnector.fetchUserById(id);
    }
}
```

Here's is some examples of the search requests which generate the above error:

```
@Service
public class ESClientConnector {

    @Value("${elastic.index}")
    private String index;

    @Autowired
    private ElasticsearchClient elasticsearchClient;
public UserProfile fetchUserById(String id) throws IOException {
           GetResponse<UserProfile> response = elasticsearchClient.get(req->
                req.index(index)
                        .id(id),UserProfile.class);
        if(!response.found())
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("User with ID" + id + " not found!");

        return response.source();
```

here is my pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.poc.es</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch-springboot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>elasticsearch-springboot</name>
    <description>Demo project for integrating elasticsearch with springboot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>co.elastic.clients</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.5.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <version>${project.parent.version}</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

**EDIT**
Just to add if I even try to create the index on ES via code i.e.

```
elasticsearchClient.indices().create(b -> b.index("test"));
```

I still get the error

```
Unexpected JSON event 'VALUE_NUMBER' instead of '[START_OBJECT, KEY_NAME]'
```

** EDIT 2**
Ok I've narrowed down the issue. If I run ES locally things work. However its when I set the ES host to my instance running in Elastic.co that triggers the error.

I've confirmed the username and password. Would this be anything todo with the the connection being HTTPs?

Comment: Look at the stack trace.  The error originates in `ESRestController.fetchUserById` calling `ESServiceImpl.fetchUserById` which called `ESClientConnector.fetchUserById`

Comment: Thanks Jim, I've updated my question above. As you can see there's nothing happening / logic in the originating methods

Answer (score 1):

A while ago, I had the exact same error. You get this error because you forgot to remove the `https://` from your `hostName` property.

Just update the code like this:

```java
@Configuration
@Getter
@Setter
public class ESRestClient {

    private String hostName = "xxxxxxx.gcp.cloud.es.io";
....
```

As you already define `https` in `new HttpHost`, it can't be in the hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Serialize DynamicMapping values as booleans instead of string.

Handle enums that have true/false values as booleans .\

[JsonMappingException: Unexpected token (START_OBJECT)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31242819/jsonmappingexception-unexpected-token-start-object)

this might be helpful

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not sure what you mean?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).